# Alineación en C

Tags: c, printf

Estoy programando en C y me ocurre el siguiente problema:
El texto no se me alinea como quiero a pesar que en el código lo especifico, pero si se me alinean los números (resultados).
A continuación dejo el código que es sacado del libro: Como programar en C/C++, Deitel, Seg.Ed, pag 111.

```
 /*
Una persona invierte $1000.00 en una cuenta de ahorros, que reditúa un interés del 5%.
Suponiendo que todo el interés se queda en depósito dentro de la cuenta, calcule e imprima
la cantidad de dinero en la cuenta, al final de cada año, durante 10 años. Para la
determinación de estas cantidades utilice la fórmula siguiente:
             a = p(1+r)^n

p  es la cantidad originada invertida (es decir, el principal)
r es la tasa anual de interés
n es el número de años
a es la cantidad en depósito al final del año n
*/
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <math.h> //pow

main()
{
   int year;
   double amount, principal = 1000.00, rate = .05;

   printf("%4s%21s\n", "Year", "Amount on deposit");

   for (year = 1; year <= 10; year++)
   {
      amount = principal * pow(1.0 + rate, year);
      printf("%4d%21.2f\n", year, amount);
   }

   getch();
   return 0;
}
```

Mi intención es que toda la tabla que genere el código este justificada a la derecha tanto los números como los títulos pero solo se me alinean los números, adjunto foto.

Como quiero que me quede:
[image]

Lo que obtengo:

[image]

Código del libro (es lo mismo que esta en código arriba):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: No entiendo la pregunta. Yo lo que veo en la imagen es que la palabra "Year" está correctamente alineada a la derecha, ya que la letra "r" coincide en vertical con la última cifra de los números 1, 2, ... 10. Y análogamente la columna "Amount on deposit" está también alineada a la derecha pues la última letra "t" coincide con el último dígito de los números en esa columna. Por tanto está todo justificado a la derecha como pides. Si querías otra cosa ¿puedes mostrar cómo sería lo que buscas?

Comment: Actualización de código: ¿Esto es lo que piedes?: https://tio.run/##VZDdasQgEIXvfYohZcFsbDChvTIp9DEKvTEx6QpZDcZQStlnT8eftqw3OuOZM9/M@PgxjsfxoM247GqCbvNK2/ryQpTdh2WC1X7S0ZrNQ05IlkJtPAzlN9Ez0KHveekmvzsDjYgpeZ/KxZtctJK9FGS2jgYL3TdCd4PQVVWS/J2uM6rQiubknV1@pS9BbiRYXaU2FIkAItzXJJ0IwS/41e7GM1gdDqtXuUAPDee85pyBk37CuObP2BRrgsjPtDg9bae22d5NwaB4Q8dwv0YnsAbUtNpN@6JMVTgU0NA3WItIAF3okt5hRFRFQjwJCKX/ROe476bmUEUkFspKkQv@oFp1atu6nSNWkLBslqS3CJN3xHE9x/ED

Comment: Hola abulafia y Daniel, acabo de editar la pregunta y agregue mas información.             Yo quiero que me quede alineado a la izquierda al igual que el libro (primera imagen), pero lo que obtengo como resultado lo que esta en la última imagen.                                                                            Si bien el código es exactamente el mismo que el del libro me da un resultado diferente.   Yo creo que el problema no esta en los números, creo que estos si se alinean. Lo que no se alinea para mi son los títulos:  Year y Amount on deposit

Comment: @Mauricho Así se llama a las persona para que esta reciva una notificacion. experimenta con estos valores: `printf("%4d%21.2f\n",....);` Cambia %4d por el numero que tu quieras y observa los resultados. Por ejemplo: %1d o %6d. Y tambien esto: %21.2f y juega con su valor. Por ejemplo: %15.2f o %30.2f. Ejemplos completos:

Comment: 1-`printf("%1d%15.2f\n",....);`   2-`printf("%6d%30.2f\n",........);`  Y si no te gusta como quedó: modificalo  a tu gusto.

Comment: @DanielBriceño si hasta altura creo que esa es la mejor solución, haciéndolo igual que el libro esta visto que no  llegamos a lo mismo; pensaba que se podía, muchas gracias amigo, saludos!

Comment: Listo. Chao hasta la proxima.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

también tuve un problema parecido hace tiempo y encontré (al menos en lo personal) que es mejor indicar separaciones poniendo números en negativo, de manera que la salida que buscas se puede formatear así `printf("%-8d%.2f\n", year, amount);`
Poniendo números en negativo haces que printf primero pinte la salida (en este caso es year) en pantalla y seguidamente hace tantos espacios como se lo indiques con el número, en este caso son 8 y a continuación pone el valor de la variable amount.

Comment: Hola @Accimus he probado lo que me indicaste y me ayudo bastante pero no del todo, sigo teniendo cierto problema para alejarlo del margen (me queda muy pegado al borde del CMD). Si bien ahora están las columnas alineadas (títulos y datos) también están pegada la columna Year al borde sin siquiera un espacio. Desde ya muchas gracias!!

Comment: En ese caso lo que puedes hacer es poner un espacio al inicio de la cadena y luego disminuir el numero, de la siguiente forma `printf(" %-7d%1.2f\n",year,amount);` el numero se disminuye en uno porque se le agrego un espacio al inicio de la cadena, si fueran dos pues se le disminuye dos unidades al numero y asi.

Comment: muchas gracias !!! Gracias por explicarme como es el que funciona, te debo una hermano!

Answer (score 0):

Puedes probar completando con ceros

```
printf("%04d%21.2f\n", year, amount);
```

Comment: Hola Sergio, he probado agregando un cero pero me tira el siguiente error al copilar: warning: '0' flag used with '%s' ms_printf format [-Wformat=]                                      Y si lo agrego en la línea de más abajo donde van los números me completa el espacio con ceros, desde ya muchas gracias

Comment: Hola, Que compilador estas usando?

Comment: Visual Studio Code